# get CORS Error when fetch from esp javascript

Tags: javascript, arduino, esp32

I set up an ESP32 Webserver which provides me Sensor Values in .json Format.
In Console i get the Error:

Error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://10.0.0.40/sensor. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

What do I have to change?​

```
// JavaScript source code
fetch('http://10.0.0.40/sensor')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

        var unit0 = data['0']['unit'];
        var unit1 = data['1']['unit'];

        var temperature = data['0']['value'];
        var humidity = data['1']['value'];

        document.getElementById("sensortemperature").innerHTML = temperature + unit0;
        document.getElementById("sensorhumidity").innerHTML = humidity + unit1;

        console.log(temperature + unit0);

    })
```

Comment: your Webserver should send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

Comment: Do you know how this has to be written? Its an ESP32 with <Webserver.h>
<WiFi.h>

Comment: likely via `server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` wherever you register the `/sensor` listener, if this is your setup https://www.hackster.io/electropeak/create-a-web-server-w-esp32-tutorial-a9a392

Comment: This doesnt work with my Library. It doesnt recognise the server.sendHeader

Comment: if I don't know which library you are using, I am not sure how you expect me, or anyone else, to help. Check your libarry documentation and send that header *before* returning the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates a CORS error:

> Error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://10.0.0.40/sensor. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

The ESP32 webserver needs to enable CORS for the browser/client requesting your sensor data.

Your comment states you are using the ESP `WebServer` library. This provides an `enableCORS()` method (see https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h#L127).

So you can enable CORS after you create the webserver like:

```
WebServer server();
server.enableCORS(true);
```